# Authlogic NoMethodError in UserSessionsController#create while login

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I did same as show in authlogin [example](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example). User is created successfully and session also maintained and logout also working fine. After logout I try to login again the application getting following error

**NoMethodError in UserSessionsController#create**

```
undefined method `[]' for false:FalseClass
```

In user_session controller

```
app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

UserSessionController Code

```
...     
 def create
   @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])
   if @user_session.save
     flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
     redirect_back_or_default user_path(current_user)
   else
     render :action => :new
   end
 end
...
```

I am using

- ruby -v ruby 1.9.2p180
- rails -v Rails 3.1.3
- authlogic (2.1.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Updating authlogic version 2.1.6 to 3.1.0 it works fine.